# How to repeat value in one column based on grouping in another column (for-loop combined with group_by?)

Tags: r, group-by

Hope to get some help here.
Have a dataframe with ID and randomisation and would like to "copypaste" values, so NA are replaced.

My dataframe:

```
person_id <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3")
randomisation <- c("treatment 2", NA, NA, "treatment 1", NA, NA, NA, "treatment 3", NA)
frame <- data.frame(person_id, randomisation)
```

This gives me frame:

```
>  person_id randomisation
> 1         1   treatment 2
> 2         1          <NA>
> 3         1          <NA>
> 4         2   treatment 1
> 5         2          <NA>
> 6         2          <NA>
> 7         2          <NA>
> 8         3   treatment 3
> 9         3          <NA>
```

Can I combine for-loop and groub_by to replace the NAs with randomisation value for the same person_id?
Tried with lag(randomisation) but without desired output.

Desired output:

```
>  person_id randomisation
> 1         1   treatment 2
> 2         1   treatment 2
> 3         1   treatment 2
> 4         2   treatment 1
> 5         2   treatment 1
> 6         2   treatment 1
> 7         2   treatment 1
> 8         3   treatment 3
> 9         3   treatment 3
```

Thanks in advance :) !

Tried:

```
frame <- frame %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Randomisation = lag(Randomise)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest maybe someone has something more elegant than this but it works:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(frame)){
   if (is.na(frame$randomisation[i])){
     match_treatment <- frame$randomisation[which(frame$person_id[i] == frame$person_id)]
     non_na_match <- match_treatment[!is.na(match_treatment)][1]
     frame$randomisation[i] <- non_na_match
   }
}
```

Output:

```
> frame
  person_id randomisation
1         1   treatment 2
2         1   treatment 2
3         1   treatment 2
4         2   treatment 1
5         2   treatment 1
6         2   treatment 1
7         2   treatment 1
8         3   treatment 3
9         3   treatment 3
```